# json4s response to case class

Tags: scala, class, case, json4s

I am getting this json response, how to create Scala Case Class for the **page_views** ??

```
"page_views": {
    "2015-12-30T21:30:00+05:30": 4,
    "2016-01-08T15:30:00+05:30": 25,
    "2016-01-13T11:30:00+05:30": 9,
    "2016-01-13T12:30:00+05:30": 8,
    "2016-01-14T10:30:00+05:30": 21,
    "2016-01-21T12:30:00+05:30": 19,
    "2016-01-21T17:30:00+05:30": 4,
    "2016-01-22T17:30:00+05:30": 2,
    "2016-02-02T10:30:00+05:30": 14,
    "2016-02-24T12:30:00+05:30": 11,
    "2016-02-26T09:30:00+05:30": 12
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries , I was able to make it work. I used a `Map` to bind to the JSON fields.

```
case class Test(page_views: Map[String, Int])
```

Answer (score 1):

First define what case class you want. Let's say it's something like `case class PageView(date:myDateType,numberViews:Long)`. Then you don't fall in the basic case where the json you receive has the fields `date` and `numberViews` explicitly written, e.g `{"date":"xxx","numberViews":123}`. So using json4s it won't be enough to create a case class and let it do the rest, you will have to write a custom (de)serializer (they have an example [here](https://github.com/json4s/json4s), search 'Serializer' on the page).

Comment: given JSON Object is no Array. So the described approach would not work : `"page_views": {
    "2015-12-30T21:30:00+05:30": 4, ...} //object`. Would only work if `"page_views": [
    { "2015-12-30T21:30:00+05:30": 4} ,... ]`

Comment: You would parse the json object and deserialize it into a `List[PageView]` by looping over its "keys" (not sure that's the right word, but in this case it is the string representing a date), e.g with `mapField`.

Answer (score 0):

you may follow up [this tutorial](http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-json/) that covers how to parse json strings to your model. It also covers some usual transformations you may need to apply to convert from the json to your case class

but your case is kinda weird, shouldn't page_views contain/be an array? how can you process the page_views json object if you don't know which fields are in it?